# What does expanding your castle do?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

You are told "good things may happen" if you expand your castle, but beyond the associated Plaza Tickets, what effect does your castle size have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 20 levels to your castle. The first few unlock abilities/perks. Subsequent castle upgrades update these abilities. The abilities you can unlock & upgrade are:

- Ability to hire batches of soldiers using Play Coins
- Receive Advice (i.e. Have Wentworth split up your forces automatically)
- Spy on the Enemy to find out which type of unit you will face next
- Conversion Rate - Upgrades how many soldiers join your forces from the enemy side upon victory.

### Unlocks:

1. **Hire soldiers** - Small batch for 5 coins
2. **Receive Advice** - from Wentworth on your army composition
3. **Hire soldiers** - Medium Batch for 10 coins
4. **Hire soldiers** - Large batch for 15 coins
5. **Spy on the enemy** - See which troops will be deployed first

### Upgrades

6. **Hire Upgrade** - Doubles the number of soldiers in all batches
7. **Hire Upgrade** - Triples the number of soldiers in all batches
8. **Advice Upgrade** - Receive advice up to two times
9. **Hire Upgrade** - Initial Size x 4
10. **Hire Upgrade** - Initial Size x 6
11. **Spy Upgrade** - Spy up to two times
12. **Conversion Upgrade** - Increases likelihood of getting soldiers from foreign kings
13. **Hire Upgrade** - Initial Size x 8
14. **Advice Upgrade** - Receive advice up to three times
15. **Hire Upgrade** - Initial Size x 11
16. **Spy Upgrade** - Spy up to three times
17. **Conversion Upgrade** - Further increases likelihood of getting soldiers from foreign kings
18. **Hire Upgrade** - Initial Size x 12
19. **Advice Upgrade** - Receive advice as often as you'd like
20. **Spy Upgrade** - Spy as often as you'd like

Source: [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/66778860)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding once gives you a ticket for a hat. Expending a second time allows you to hire 300 troops for ten coins. That's all I've done so far.