# Does my castle style choice have any impact on gameplay?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

Does the castle style I choose at the beginning of *Warrior's Way* have any impact on the gameplay/sidequests/etc of the game? Or is it just about aesthetics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 choices of castle, but they are purely aesthetic choices - only *upgrading* your castle affects gameplay.

When you upgrade your castle, you gain perks at the cost of converting some of your warriors to craftsmen. The perks you gain are detailed on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133978/28182).

To upgrade your castle, you must come across some 'resources' after defeating a nation (which look like a pile of wood and bricks). You will then get the option of upgrading your castle.

For completeness sake, the choices of castle you have are:

- Japanese
- Western
- Futuristic

You also cannot alter the choice of castle after you've chosen it.