# What is the use of being able to ask for advice twice?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

I recently got the [upgrade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122764/what-does-expanding-your-castle-do) which allows you to ask for advice twice rather than just once per session.

**What is this good for?**

As far as I can tell, you can have at most one battle per session, and therefore you only organize your troops once. Won't asking for advice again just tell me the same thing it did the first time? Or will it perhaps give me better advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think double advice is not to help you to choose **how many guys** of each categories you'll use, but it allows you to request spying **when it's your turn to send your troops** (send the bow-men, the horse-men…).

That way, you can know during the second or third turn which men your opponent will send. It can be useful in case of a particularly hard battle (e.g. against ninjas + you having not as many men to deal).

My English isn't perfect + I don't play the game in English, so forgive me. ^^

Hope I could help. :)